# Image not displayed in Outlook when Python script is run through bat file

Tags: python, html, image, batch-file, base64

I have an image which is converted into base64 and it is included in my python script. I want the image to be displayed in Outlook automatically and it needs to be shared to different participants.
However when I run the bat script, the image is not getting displayed in my mail.
Any idea as to what change is required?

```py
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.subject = 'Test Mail'
mail.To = 'mail id'

html_body = '''\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="images">
            <center><img src="data:image/png;base64, <image_converted_base64format>"></center>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''
mail.HTMLBody = html_body
mail.Send()
```

A bat file is created and the bat file contains the following line:

```bash
@echo off
"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Scripts\Python_Test.py"
timeout /t 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve this issue by including `mail.Display()` above `mail.Send()` and the image is getting displayed in the Outlook mail sent to participants